# Uploaded a Video on Vimeo

Tags: video, upload, vimeo

I have uploaded video on Vimeo, and I can view them in my vimeo account,But how can I get the video no. or get back the video link of that particular video in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just see the links below and follow the steps in 

 https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload

1) HTTP PUT to upload a file in Java

2) http://pastebin.com/79iSxzmR

Note:- i used scribe library at https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java which provides with methods used in above links (1) and (2).

Comment: The Advanced API is no longer supported by Vimeo and will be deactivated in the near future. Switch to the new API as soon as possible to avoid service disruption: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the new API, getting the video uri/video id depends on the method you use to upload.

For [simple POST uploads](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#simple-http-post-uploading) after the client has completed upload, the user is sent to the redirect url provided earlier in the upload process. That redirect URL will have a new parameter `video_uri` added.

For [resumable PUT uploads](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#complete-the-upload), the `video_uri` is returned after making the final DELETE call to the `complete_uri` returned earlier in the upload process.

If you're not using the API and you just want the URL of your newly uploaded video, go to vimeo.com, hover over your avatar in the top right-hand corner of the page, and select Videos; your latest upload will appear at the top.

Comment: How can we get the complete_uri for DELETE call??

Comment: I have attempted DELETE call on one of my video after uploading,but it gives me 500 internal error as response code ,is it because the status of my video is still uploading??If yes then how long does it take to change the status to available?

Comment: Verify that your upload has completed before making the DELETE call: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#verify-the-upload

Comment: Yes I verify the upload by performing PUT request again without sending file with my request and I get a 308 response code along with range header

Comment: Is there any file size limit for uploading videos ? For below 10 mb, it is working fine but for larger sizes ,it doesn't upload .

Comment: No file size limit besides your account's weekly quota.

Comment: How do send the video files while uploading because i hv kept buffersize of 10 MB ,so only that much data is uploaded,Can u please help me out??

Comment: can u please share me code to upload video in bytes??